# I am unable to sort with orderBy pipe for nested objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a array of objects. I want to sort some keys using orderBy pipe but due to the fact that i there are objects in the main object. I am unable to use the pipe.

example object

```
    var object = {
    Name :'John',
    City : 'Dallas',
    Address:{
    Street: 'xyz',
    Postal_code:123,
    }
}
```

so I have 1000 such objects in array,when i Use the orderBy pipe I am able to sort the keys but i am unable to sort the keys inside address object.

```
*ngFor = "object of objects | orderBy:'object.Address.Street':false"
```

This dint work. Can you guys please suggest some solutions.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see `City` under `Address`.

Comment: your object is invalid and city isnt in address

Comment: Sorry i corrected it

Comment: your object is still invalid

Comment: `orderBy` is custom pipe?

Comment: No it is Angular pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `build-in` orderBy pipe available in angular.

These are the only built-in pipes available for usage in templates.

[build-in pipes Angular](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#built-in-pipes)

You will have to create a custom pipe for this. Read more about creating pipes here: [Custom pipes in angular](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

In your approach, you will have to use:

```
*ngFor = "object of objects | orderBy:'object.Address.Street':false"
```

Comment: This project has been deprecated.

Comment: I am unable to pass through the objects to sort.

Comment: Check my above edit. you should use object.Address.street

Comment: Yes I have just typed some example there but i have called the exprsession as you mentioned but it didn.t work.

Comment: Don't use a pipe to sort an array. just sort the array by code